# Bibliography on how to data preprocessing

Tags: references, data-preprocessing

Very often we're given a data set which contains duplicate rows, missing values, outliers, etc.

Most of the information on how to deal with these situations (from a statistical perspective) is disaggregated, and sometimes incomplete.

I was wondering if there's a textbook, or another kind of bibliography which dealt with these issues.

I'm looking for a more applied perspective and not so much theoretical.

Comment: I wonder where "data preprocessing" ends and data *analysis* begins.  Without some criterion--even if it's artificial--you would be asking for a bibliography of all exploratory data analysis along, perhaps, with the literature on database design and management.  Could you narrow the focus of this question?

Comment: If correcting for missing values is included in preprocessing, then dividing between preprocessing and analysis seems difficult. This is because some missing data methods (eg multiple imputation) are only valid when the analysis model is compatible with the missing data method. Although perhaps some criterion could be used to delineate describing missing values from analysing data with missing values.

Comment: @whuber my lack of knowledge in the area may hinder me from narrowing the focus. For example, I wasn't even aware of techniques David alludes to, in his comment.

At this point, I take whatever advice you have. I just need a foot in the door, then I'll let myself enter. The only thing I can say is that Im not so interested in database design and management.

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen Given my lack of knowledge on the area, I'll take almost any suggestion you have. Give me a bunch of them, and I'll skim them through to check which one is more similar to what I want.

Comment: It can be useful to study what is being taught in the colleges.  See [this course description](https://catalog.middlebury.edu/courses/view/catalog/catalog%2FMCUG/course/course%2FMATH0216) for instance. A semester is devoted to "the entire data science pipeline: forming a statistical question, collecting and cleaning data sets, performing exploratory data analyses, identifying appropriate statistical techniques, and communicating the results..." Your question seems to focus on the "collecting and cleaning" part.